# Stub/Assert method on same object as the method beeing tested with Mocha and Sinon

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

Simplified I have the following object, where I want to assert that subFunc has been called from func.

```
export function subFunc(arg) {
  return arg + 'bar';
};

export function func(arg) {
  return subFunc(arg);
};
```

I have the following test, which fails on both the assertion of subFunc beeing called and the expected returnvalue.

Even though I am stubbing the subFunc, the original method is beeing used.

If the subFunc is on another object than the object beeing tested it works fine.

```
import * as testObject from '../testObject';

...

it('does not work', () => {
  const subFuncStub = sinon.stub(testObject, 'subFunc');
  subFuncStub.returns('something else');

  const value = testObject.func('foo');

  sinon.assert.called(subFuncStub); // Never called
  expect(value).to.be.equal('something else'); // Is 'foobar'
});
```

Why is this not working and how can I stub a method on the same object as the method beeing tested?

Answer (score 0):

When you stub, you basically dont call actual function, and check that on calling one function, the stubbed function is called with Args( basically the arguements it expects).

If you are actually looking for functional output, you might not stub it, but mock the data to be passed.

Comment: I am mocking the return value to 'something else', and would expect that to be returned, and not the value from the original subFunc. I'm looking for a way to assert that the method has called the sub-method, where the sub-method is located on the same object that the method I am testing.

Comment: And the action funcion IS called, even though I am subbing it, because the return values comes from the actual function.